# Grails Spring Security Failed Password Attempt

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, pre-authentication

Is there a way to retrieve user entered password in spring security core grails plugin when the authentication fails in the action authfail of LoginController?

```
def authfail = {

def msg = ''

// I can get the username as below
def username = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]

// There is UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY but the value is null when access here as below   
def attemptedPassword = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY]
.
.
.
}
```

I need to be able to know the password entered when the authentication fails.

Comment: There is no way to get spring security password in plain text. If authentication fail then show password field as blank.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you have to store the password in session before submitting login form. Add custom button to your login form and hide submit button:

```
<form action="/j_spring_security_check">
   ...
   <button onclick="javascript:store()" type="button">Login</button>
   <input class="invisible" id="loginButton" type="submit">
</form>
```

You need to write `store()` function in javascript. Here is an example how to achieve that: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pKXMa/) (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193574/save-javascript-objects-in-sessionstorage)). Obviously in this function you must enclose form submission (using jQuery): `$('#loginButton').click()`

After failed authentication you have to retrieve stored password.