# Auto Saving HTML form in Session Storage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, session, session-storage

I have an app which contains a HTML form, the form uses AngularJS meaning textfields use `ng-model` to save data into objects within the `$scope`.

Example:

**In HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName">
```

**In the controller:**

```
$scope.user = {}
```

Now what I am trying to do is auto save user data as they type it within the session storage so if the page gets reloaded/refresh accidentally the data is still there and they don't have to type it all again.

**I have tired this:**

```
 <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="Background" name="Background" ng-model="obj.background" ng-change="autosave()" required></textarea>
```

In the above code I have `ng-change` function that runs when the state of the text field changes.

```
 $scope.autosave = function(){
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", $scope.obj);
}
```

The above code outputs into this:

[image]

**My Question:**

How can I properly make this work so all fields in the form are autosaved and if the page accidentally refreshes the field are populated again with the data. This is the first time I am working with session storage so Im a little confused.

Whats the most efficient way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it as JSON data instead of doing it directly as an object.

```
var obj = {};
obj.name = "dooley"
obj.last = "bonheuaa"

window.sessionStorage.setItem("me", JSON.stringify( obj));
```

After refreshing the page you can do the following to get it back

```
var me = JSON.parse( window.sessionStorage.getItem("me"))
```

now me will have the value of the object stored.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would you recommend I populate the textfields with the data from session after page refresh?

Comment: You can have a script that simply retrieves the object from sessionstorage. Then you can do things like: $("#id").val(me.name). Obviously you want to make sure it is there before using it with an if statement or something

Comment: I have tried that but it only works if I remove the ng-model from the text field. Otherwise it doesnt populate the text field.

Comment: I would say Update the model instead of accessing it directly, but idk how that's implemented

Answer (score 0):

In SessionStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), you can only put String object.

So, i recommend you to use Stringify on get/set of the sessionStorage.
 [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193574/save-javascript-objects-in-sessionstorage) for more information.