# How to Display All Values in Email Body that are Checked Regardless if Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, checkbox

I have a multiple column table with one column being checkboxes. If you check a checkbox then press the "Checkout" button, it will take the specified rows and display them in the body of an email.

I originally bring in the top 100 rows to keep the info to a minimum for the user. I also have a search functionality where the user can search for specific rows. The user can maneuver throughout different searches and still keep all of the checkboxes checked with session storage. However, when a user hits "Checkout" the body of the email only displays the table rows that are checked and **currently visible on the page.**

So, if a user searches for a table row and checks it, but then navigates back to the original top 100 rows by clicking home, that row would not display on the email because it is not displayed in the top 100.

How can I fix this and show ALL rows that have been checked, whether they are visible on the page or not?

JavaScript that sends information to email body:

```
function sendMail() {
    var dataItems = [
        { 'clss':'.loc',         'prop':'loc' },
        { 'clss':'.rp-code',     'prop':'rpCode' },
        { 'clss':'.sku',         'prop':'sku' },
        { 'clss':'.special-id',  'prop':'specialId' },
        { 'clss':'.description', 'prop':'description' },
        { 'clss':'.quantity',    'prop':'quantity' },
        { 'clss':'.unit',        'prop':'unit' }
    ];
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=";
    link += $('#merchTable tr input[name="check"]:checked').closest('tr').get().map(function(tr) {
            var str = dataItems.map(function(item) {
                return encodeURIComponent($(tr).find(item.clss).data(item.prop)) + '\xa0\xa0';
            }).join('');
            str += encodeURIComponent($(tr).find('.spinner').spinner('value')) + '%0D%0A';
            return str;
        }).join('') + '%0D%0A';
    console.log(link);
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

JavaScript that includes code to keep all checkboxes checked throughout session:

```
$(function(){
    var showQuantityHeader = false;
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
        var $el = $(this);
        //console.log('element id: ',$el.prop('id'),' sessionStorage[id]: ',sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')]);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
        if ($el.prop('checked')) {          
            //show the quantity cell in the column under header with class num
            $el.closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
            showQuantityHeader = true;
            setupSpinner(this);
            var quantity = sessionStorage['value_'+$el.prop('id')];
            if (quantity) {
                $el.closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner( "value", quantity );
            }
        }
    });

    if (showQuantityHeader) {
            $('#merchTable').find('th.num').show();
        //console.log('header with class num: ',$('#merchTable').find('th.num'));
    }

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        // save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
        // using the checkbox "id" attribute
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
    });
});
```

HTML Table:

```
<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button id="checkout" name="order" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Checkout</button>
</section>

<br>

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" data-loc="<?php echo $row['Loc'] ?>"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" data-rp-code="<?php echo $row['Rp-Code'] ?>" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td class="sku ui-widget-content" data-sku="<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td class="special-id ui-widget-content" data-special-id="<?php echo $row['Special-ID'] ?>" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td class="description ui-widget-content" data-description="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Description']) ?>" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td class="unit ui-widget-content" data-unit="<?php echo $row['Unit'] ?>" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input disabled="true" type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Read the items from session instead of from the UI.

Comment: @mjw Would you be able to expand on this and what I would need to do?

Comment: You've got some code above that saves data off to session when a checkbox is checked. So why do you want to go back to the UI to read the list of selected items when you have the overall selected list independent of what is shown on the screen? Load the list in from session and build the email from this list.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how this might be done?

Comment: You have used sessionStorage in your code above. Is it safe to assume you didn't write the code in your question? Try this for some info on using sessionStorage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193574/save-javascript-objects-in-sessionstorage

Comment: Okay, so it makes sense when you say I'm storing in session storage but pulling from the UI. So would I need to change this line of code `$('#merchTable tr input[name="check"]:checked')` in the `link` variable to pull the checked rows from the session?