# How to get state item via props in vuejs with vuex

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I'm sorry for my bad english. 
I've fromSelected props in vue. I want to get state selected item via props value.

I've from component.

```
<template>
    <h1>this.$store.state.fromSelected</h1>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
       props: ['fromSelected']
    }
</script>
```

in vuex state like this

```
const state = {
   'one': null,
}
```

I use my from component in root component like this

```
<from from-selected="one"></from>
```

When I use *this.$store.state.fromSelected* I want to get *this.$store.state.one* in from component.

Comment: can you make any live demo ?

Comment: via online editor or video?

Comment: here in code snippet

Comment: Checkout the answer to this question I answered the other day; it explains how to get a store objects state in your current component https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489786/vue-js-and-vue-datepicker-save-a-picked-period-in-the-global-state/50490730#50490730

Comment: no. Please come here https://codeshare.io/GbpJkv

Comment: It's not live demo

Comment: Do you want to pass the value from the state to the component? Like this: `State -> Controller -> Use inside template`?

Comment: when I use this.$store.state.one I can get state.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vngrcu5v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem you are facing has to do with the flow of the data in Vue and Vuex. There are two different problems that need to be addressed here:

#### Problem nr. 1 - Data Flow and Scopes:

In your template code: `<h1>this.$store.state.fromSelected</h1>` you are trying to access the component property in the Vuex state. It will not exist there as it only exists in the components local scope. Here is an illustration of how the flow of data would work:

[image]

#### Problem nr. 2 - Static and Dynamic Props:

In the line `<from from-selected="one"></from>` you are not prepending the property with a colon and therefore the prop will be considered a string literal and not an expression where you could pass in a variable. Read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Static-and-Dynamic-Props

#### Solution:

The solution would be to pass in the value from the Vuex state as a dynamic property to the component; like this:

```
// Javascript
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    one: "This comes from the Vuex state"
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store: store,
  components: {
    from: {
      template: '<span>{{ fromSelected }}</span>',
      props: ['fromSelected']
    }
  }
})

// Template
<div id="app">
  <from :from-selected="$store.state.one"></from>
</div>
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vngrcu5v/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put **fromSelected** with same syntax?

```
<from fromSelected="one"></from>
```

Comment: In Vue.js you would specify the props as camelCase when defining the controller and use hyphen-case when using the components props in HTML.

Comment: Ah ok , i never use camelCase .. thk

Answer (score 0):

Ifound. I must write like this.

```
// From.vue component
<template>
   <span>{{this.fromSelected}}</span>


 </template>
    <script>
       export default {
            props: ['fromSelected']
       }
    </script>



// Root component
    import from from 'from';

    <from :from-selected="this.$store.state.one"></from>



// State 
export default {
   'one': null,
}
```

Comment: Is this based on my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vngrcu5v/ ? If so, do you want me to clean up the answer so it will be more understandable for others finding this question?

Comment: yes. Your code is perfect. I just use your code. thanks for all

Comment: No worries. I have made a more complete answer now to address all the problems. Please accept my answer if it is correct.