# How to make an array of objects from an array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This is driving me crazy.

I have an array like so:

```
myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', ];
```

and my code is making a NEW object that will look like this:

```
myNewObj = [
 {
   name: "A",
   displayName: "A"
 },
 {
   name: "B",
   displayName: "B"
 },
 {
   name: "C",
   displayName: "C"
 },
 {
   name: "C",
   displayName: "C"
 },
 {
   name: "D",
   displayName: "D"
 },
 {
   name: "E",
   displayName: "E"
 },
 {
   name: "F",
   displayName: "F"
 }
]
```

My code gets values in the myArray and I want to create myNewObj

This is how I'm doing it so far

I create the new object

```
let newObj = [{
    "name": "",
    "displayName": ""
}];
```

Then I use a simple FOR NEXT loop and it work up until a point and claims newObj[i].name IS UNDEFINED... how is that possible when I'm defining it and see it in the Google dev console?

```
            for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                newObj[i].name = myArray[i];
                newObj[i].displayName = myArray[i];

                myNewObj.push(newObj);
            }
```

However, I consistently get this error:

newObj[i].name is NOT DEFINED and it dies.

UPDATE: Everything's working and here's the ACTUAL real data

But as you can see, the prototype is there and when I save to sessionStorage, I get [Object,Object], x 12....

[image]

do I need to strip out name: and displayName: and put into yet another object?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array#map`:

```js
const myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

const myNewArray = myArray.map(e => ({ name: e, displayName: e }));

console.log(myNewArray);
```

Your solution (you need to initialize the array as `[]` and create a new object in every iteration to push it):

```js
const myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

const myNewArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  obj.name = myArray[i];
  obj.displayName = myArray[i];
  myNewArray.push(obj);
}

console.log(myNewArray);
```

Comment: Please see update. It's all working great but ProtoType is causing [object Object]....

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193574/save-javascript-objects-in-sessionstorage

Answer (score 2):

**Issue with the code**

You are doing the `Array.Push` incorrectly. Your `let newObj` should be an object, not an array. It should be initialized inside the loop. so that each execution takes a different memory location. You should define `myNewObj` as an empty array and should push your `newObj` into `myNewObj` array inside the loop.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const myNewObj = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  let newObj = {
    "name": "",
    "displayName": ""
  };
  newObj.name = myArray[i];
  newObj.displayName = myArray[i];
  myNewObj.push(newObj);
};
console.log(myNewObj);
```

**Better Approach**

A better approach for this issue is to use `Array.map`. `Array.map` returns a new array from an existing array. You could run `Array.map` on `myArray` and construct `myNewObj` array as below.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const myNewObj = myArray.map((item) => ({ name: item, dispayName: item}));
console.log(myNewObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', ];
var myNewObj = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            var newObj = {
            name:'',
            displayName:''
            };
                newObj['name'] = myArray[i];
                newObj['displayName'] = myArray[i];

                myNewObj.push(newObj);
}
console.log(myNewObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're trying to define `newObj` as an array with one object for some reason. Just create a new object.
2. Create a new object within the scope of the loop for each iteration. You can then just push that object into the empty output array.

```js
const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  obj.name = letters[i];
  obj.displayName = letters[i];
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```